# QQplot vs BoxPlot

Tags: normality-assumption, qq-plot, boxplot

I am having trouble reading my qqplots. I want to asses normality graphically before I carry out a test like shaparo test(my sample is small (<50)) . So I  have two question is the qqplot better than a box plot for assessing normality and if so why.

In  my analyses I carried plotted the qqplot and the points lye more or less along the line therefore we could not reject the normality assumption, but I wasn't quite sure as I found the plot hard to read so from the box plot it is very slightly skewed to the left. Any feed back on this would be much appreciated.[image: Box Plot v QQ plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a QQ plot you show all the data points; with a box plot you lose a substantial amount of detail. So yes, QQ-plot is better for looking at normality. Just looking at the graph I would say that your variable is a bit heavy tailed, but for many applications it will be close enough to being normal.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the box plot is you have no reference distribution against which to compare your sample, so little way of assessing normality.  The Q-Q plot is much better suited to this purpose.  Or you could compare a histogram of your sample with a normal density with the same mean and variance ([here is a thread from Stack Overflow about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939136/how-to-overlay-density-plots-in-r)).  This would be arguably easier to understand than the Q-Q plot.

Comment: Very good point with the histogram, however we have covered box plots and we are on qq-plots and and I was just wondering what the differences were in them when assessing normality and I was hoping to get some feed back on my qq-plot.